# Windows Microsoft .net Error Keeps Occuring

Tags: windows

First Of All, I posted this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030059/windows-microsoft-net-error-keeps-occuring) and they told me to post it here, they told me, Ask for advice on how to get your disk drive healthy again, so, i'm asking, how can  i get  my disk drive healthy again?

The error that keeps popping up when opening some certain programs is at the bottom of the post, if you can help me, it would be greatly apreciated!!

Error:

```
Zie het einde van dit bericht voor meer informatie over het aanroepen 
van JIT-foutopsporing (Just In Time) in plaats van dit dialoogvenster.

************** Tekst van uitzondering **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Kan bestand of assembly Accessibility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a of een van de afhankelijkheden hiervan niet laden. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
Bestandsnaam: Accessibility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   bij DVDVideoSoft.Utils.Splash.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmCreate(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRSCH: registratie van assembly-bindingen is uitgeschakeld.
Als u assembly-bindingsfouten wilt registreren, stelt u de registerwaarde [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) in op 1.
Opmerking: er is een prestatiestraf gekoppeld aan de registratie van assembly-bindingsfouten.
Als u deze functie wilt uitschakelen, verwijdert u de registerwaarde [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



************** Geladen assembly's **************
mscorlib
    Assembly-versie: 2.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
FreeYouTubeToMP3Converter
    Assembly-versie: 3.11.22.508
    Win32-versie: 3.11.22.0508
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/DVDVideoSoft/Free%20Studio/Free%20YouTube%20to%20MP3%20Converter/FreeYouTubeToMP3Converter.exe
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Assembly-versie: 2.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
DVDVideoSoft.Utils
    Assembly-versie: 1.0.333.0
    Win32-versie: 3.11.22.0508
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/DVDVideoSoft/Free%20Studio/Free%20YouTube%20to%20MP3%20Converter/FreeYouTubeToMP3Converter.exe
----------------------------------------
DVDVideoSoft.DialogForms
    Assembly-versie: 1.1.4.0
    Win32-versie: 3.11.22.0508
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/DVDVideoSoft/Free%20Studio/Free%20YouTube%20to%20MP3%20Converter/FreeYouTubeToMP3Converter.exe
----------------------------------------
DVDVideoSoft.AppFx
    Assembly-versie: 1.0.0.1
    Win32-versie: 3.11.22.0508
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/DVDVideoSoft/Free%20Studio/Free%20YouTube%20to%20MP3%20Converter/FreeYouTubeToMP3Converter.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly-versie: 2.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 2.0.50727.5460 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly-versie: 2.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly-versie: 2.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 2.0.50727.5462 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
DVDVideoSoft.AppFxApi
    Assembly-versie: 1.0.0.1
    Win32-versie: 3.11.22.0508
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/DVDVideoSoft/Free%20Studio/Free%20YouTube%20to%20MP3%20Converter/FreeYouTubeToMP3Converter.exe
----------------------------------------
DVDVideoSoft.Resources
    Assembly-versie: 0.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 0.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/DVDVideoSoft/Free%20Studio/Free%20YouTube%20to%20MP3%20Converter/DVDVideoSoft.Resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly-versie: 8.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 8.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Assembly-versie: 2.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/2.0.0.0_nl_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly-versie: 2.0.0.0
    Win32-versie: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT-foutopsporing **************
Als u JIT-foutopsporing wilt inschakelen, moet in het configuratiebestand voor deze
toepassing of computer (machine.config) de waarde
jitDebugging in het gedeelte system.windows.forms zijn ingesteld.
De toepassing moet ook zijn gecompileerd terwijl foutopsporing
was ingeschakeld.

Bijvoorbeeld:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

Wanneer JIT-foutopsporing is ingeschakeld, worden onverwerkte uitzonderingen
naar het JIT-foutopsporingsprogramma gestuurd dat op de computer is geregistreerd
en worden niet door dit dialoogvenster verwerkt.
```

Comment: Please don't cross post. If your question was in the wrong place it could have been migrated here.

Comment: Its not crossposting, i placed i in StackOverFlow, and someone told me, i might wanted to ask  here to

Comment: Still haven't got a answer...

Comment: Could you please translate the error message to English so those of us who don't speak Dutch can have a chance of helping you?